# how to use the IntentSpy to spy on intents

Tags: android, testing, android-intent

this sounds really good:
https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testrunner/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/intento/IntentSpy.java

but I found no documentation on how to use it - can someone provide some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

info from Stephan Linzner - an google employee ( via G+ ):

> +mister ligi Intento was initially part of espresso but had been stripped for the preview release. Apparently there are still some
>   references in the code which where not easily removable. So basically
>   if you look at GIT you can see how Intento intercepts Intents and
>   records them using IntentSpy. But what's missing is the actual
>   implementation, which will be released soon.

Comment: Let me add that also according to a talk Stephan Linzner gave at Droidcon 2014 Berlin, Intento will be soon released by Google as part of their android-test-kit.